# SQL Update Table query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a SQL table that needs to be updated with data from another table.
It seems like a very simple query, however I am unable to update my table.

```
CustID      FirstCommunicationDate  SecondCommunicationDate
20144       2013/02/01      2013/02/16
20156       2013/02/10      2013/02/16
20755       2013/02/09      2013/02/16
20814       2013/04/14      2013/02/16
20903       2013/06/12      2013/02/16
21333       2013/06/21      2013/02/16


CustID      CommunicationNum    CommunicationDate
20144       1           2013/02/16
20144       1           2013/03/13
20144       2           2013/04/18
20903       1           2013/02/12
20903       1           2013/03/19
20903       2           2013/04/04
21333       1           2013/02/16
21333       1           2013/02/22
21333       2           2013/04/29
```

My update query is:

```
UPDATE tblCommunication
SET FirstCommunicationDate = (SELECT MAX(CommunicationDate)
                FROM FieldData fd
                WHERE CustID = fd.CustID
                AND fd.CommunicationNum = 1)
WHERE CustID IN (SELECT CustID FROM FieldData)
```

The outcome I am looking for is:

```
CustID      FirstCommunicationDate  SecondCommunicationDate
20144       2013/03/13      2013/02/16
20903       2013/03/19      2013/02/16
21333       2013/02/22      2013/02/16
```

How can I update the dates in the tblCommunication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update a
set a.FirstCommunicationDate = b.MaxDate
from tblCommunication as a
inner join (select 
                CustID
                ,MAX(CommunicationDate) as MaxDate
            from FieldData
            where CommunicationNum = 1
            group by CustID) as b
    on a.CustID = b.CustID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE tblCommunication
SET FirstCommunicationDate = (SELECT MAX(CommunicationDate)
                FROM FieldData fd
                WHERE t.CustID = fd.CustID
                AND fd.CommunicationNum = 1)
FROM tblCommunication t
WHERE t.CustID IN (SELECT CustID FROM FieldData)
```

Comment: No problem, both answers appear reasonable, choose the one that suits you. Use show execution plan to see if there is an edge in one approach versus the other. The query optimizer tends to figure things out more often then not.